# setf in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp, setf

I know I can do the following in Common Lisp:

```
CL-USER> (let ((my-list nil))
       (dotimes (i 5)
         (setf my-list (cons i my-list)))
       my-list)
(4 3 2 1 0)
```

How do I do this in Clojure?  In particular, how do I do this without having a setf in Clojure?

Comment: In Common Lisp this would be shorter written as (loop for i downfrom 4 to 0 collect i) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure bans mutation of local variables for the sake of thread safety, but it is still possible to write loops even without mutation. In each run of the loop you want to `my-list` to have a different value, but this can be achieved with recursion as well:

```
(let [step (fn [i my-list]
             (if (< i 5)
               my-list
               (recur (inc i) (cons i my-list))))]
  (step 0 nil))
```

Clojure also has a way to "just do the looping" without making a new function, namely `loop`. It looks like a `let`, but you can also jump to beginning of its body, update the bindings, and run the body again with `recur`.

```
(loop [i 0
       my-list nil]
  (if (< i 5)
    my-list
    (recur (inc i) (cons i my-list))))
```

"Updating" parameters with a recursive tail call can look very similar to mutating a variable but there is one important difference: when you type `my-list` in your Clojure code, its meaning will always always *the value* of `my-list`. If a nested function closes over `my-list` and the loop continues to the next iteration, the nested function will always see the value that `my-list` had when the nested function was created. A local variable can always be replaced with its value, and the variable you have after making a recursive call is in a sense a different variable.

(The Clojure compiler performs an optimization so that no extra space is needed for this "new variable": When a variable needs to be remembered its value is copied and when `recur` is called the old variable is reused.)

Comment: you starting with i=0, dec it every step and stopping when i < 5 - that means immediately :) probably you mean inc and i > 5.

Comment: you probably still have to fix < to > ... sorry for that)

Answer (score 8):

My personal translation of what you are doing in Common Lisp would Clojurewise be:

```
(into (list) (range 5))
```

which results in:

```
(4 3 2 1 0)
```

A little explanation:

The function `into` conjoins all elements to a collection, here a new list, created with `(list)`, from some other collection, here the range `0 .. 4`. The behavior of `conj` differs per data structure. For a list, `conj` behaves as `cons`: it puts an element at the head of a list and returns that as a new list. So what is does is this:

```
(cons 4 (cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 (cons 0 (list))))))
```

which is similar to what you are doing in Common Lisp. The difference in Clojure is that we are returning new lists all the time, instead of altering one list. Mutation is only used when really needed in Clojure.

Of course you can also get this list right away, but this is probably not what you wanted to know:

```
(range 4 -1 -1)
```

or

```
(reverse (range 5))
```

or... the shortest version I can come up with:

```
'(4 3 2 1 0)
```

;-).

Answer (score 7):

Augh the way to do this in Clojure is to not do it: Clojure hates mutable state (it's available, but using it for every little thing is discouraged). Instead, notice the pattern: you're really computing `(cons 4 (cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 (cons 0 nil)))))`. That looks an awful lot like a reduce (or a fold, if you prefer). So, `(reduce (fn [acc x] (cons x acc)) nil (range 5))`, which yields the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For this I would use `range` with the manually set step:

```
(range 4 (dec 0) -1) ; => (4 3 2 1 0)
```

`dec` decreases the end step with 1, so that we get value 0 out.

Answer (score 1):

```
user=> (range 5)
(0 1 2 3 4)
user=> (take 5 (iterate inc 0))
(0 1 2 3 4)
user=> (for [x [-1 0 1 2 3]]
         (inc x)) ; just to make it clear what's going on
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

`setf` is state mutation.  Clojure has very specific opinions about that, and provides the tools for it *if you need it*.  You don't in the above case.

Answer (score 1):

```
(let [my-list (atom ())]
  (dotimes [i 5]
    (reset! my-list (cons i @my-list)))
  @my-list)

(def ^:dynamic my-list nil);need ^:dynamic in clojure 1.3
(binding [my-list ()]
  (dotimes [i 5]
    (set! my-list (cons i my-list)))
  my-list)
```

Comment: data structure in clojure is  desired　to be immutable, except in special cases.

Comment: I think the OA is a common lisper and wanted to know how to `setf` in clojure. And this is perfectly valid answer. Instead of showing "the clojure way".

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern I was looking for:

```
(loop [result [] x 5]
  (if (zero? x)
    result
    (recur (conj result x) (dec x))))
```

I found the answer in [*Programming Clojure* (Second Edition) by Stuart Halloway and Aaron Bedra](http://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure).